# Modeling Business Rules into database

Tags: database, design-patterns, architecture, business-rules

There's any pattern or modeling technique to store business rules in database?
I'm looking for something that gives to my system business rules the same extensibility that EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) gives-me in terms of fields.

Comment: Give some examples of the business rules in your system and what do you mean by extensibility? Add more rules?

Comment: Add more rules. I want that business analysts be able to add more rules without doing code.

Answer (score 4):

"Business Rules" is one of those phrases that change meaning depending on who uses them. I'm assuming that you mean firstly that you need a way of executing logic in your application that applies to every business transaction, that can be managed by non-technical people, and that allows those rules to change over time.

If that is the case, the common architectural solution is to integrate a [business rules engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine), rather than build this yourself. It's a non-trivial problem - modelling the business domain and picking the points where rules may be applied is hard enough, but then write a domain-specific language for those rules, in a way that end users can modify through a user-friendly GUI without slowing the system to a crawl is hard.

Examples of business rule engines are [Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools/) and [Visual Rules](http://www.visual-rules.com). Both are fairly involved pieces of software - worth reading up and making sure they are what you need!